# Real Time stacked area chart with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, stacked-area-chart

I want to create a chart with Highcharts in the form of a stacked area chart that is updated in real time.

I'm having problems with dynamically updating multiple stacked area charts though, you can see an example in the fiddle below.

When new points are added, the chart looks broken.

Is it possible to have dynamically updated area charts that are stacked?

```
  $(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'area'
    },
    series: [{
      data: [29, 20, 15]
    }, {
      data: [29, 20, 15]
    }, {
      data: [10, 20,15]
    }, {
      data: [10, 20, 15]
    }],
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        lineColor: '#666666',
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColor: '#666666'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }
  // the button action
  $('#button').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].addPoint(getRandomInt(1, 20), true, true);
    chart.series[1].addPoint(getRandomInt(1, 20), true, true);
    chart.series[2].addPoint(getRandomInt(1, 20), true, true);
    chart.series[3].addPoint(getRandomInt(1, 20), true, true);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yZSzZ/199/

Comment: It looks odd as `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1, which is well off the scale of your chart

Comment: I think that you have also some problems with redrawing your chart. Better idea is to use redraw after you will add all of your points. Here you can see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yZSzZ/200/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok I fixed that now, but the problem remains